# Window with no WindowPattern.Pattern

Tags: c#, .net, automation, ui-automation

I'm writing an app for automation, and I came across a problem.

I need to check if window (`ControlType.Window`) is modal and afaik `WindowPattern` provides such information, but when I list supported patterns, there are only the following:

```
ScrollPatternIdentifiers.Pattern
WindowPatternIdentifiers.Pattern
TransformPatternIdentifiers.Pattern
```

How can I get either `WindowsPattern` or `IsModalProperty` from `WindowPatternIdentifiers`?

Is it similar in any way? Some sample code would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: What does element.GetCurrentPattern(WindowPattern.Pattern) return?

Comment: It throws exception that pattern is not available.

Comment: Strange. Are you sure you're looking at the same element? A piece of code could help also. Per documentation an element of ControlType Window *must* support the Window Pattern: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee671193.aspx